# What does the "?" mean in generated language grammar?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, regular-expressions

I know  $a^*$  means that a string could be composed of zero to infinite  $a$'s, and $a^+$ means one or more $a$'s. But the professor posted this question...

Given the regular expression $b?a(a|b)ab?$
Do the strings "aaaba" , "baabb" belong to the language defined by this regular expression?

I don't need the answer to the problem, what I need to know is what does the $?$ symbol mean???

Comment: Usually, $?$ means zero or one occurrences of any character in the alphabet.

Comment: Also note that $a^*$ means an arbitrary *finite* number of $a$'s (possibly none), but not infinitely many $a$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X?$ probably means that $X$ may or may not appear at that point. Formally, you can consider it an abbreviation for $$(X|\epsilon)$$ where $\epsilon$ means the empty string.